# lambda function was always runnning when attached to dynamoDB as trigger point

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am trying to invoke one lambda function with dynamoDB if any new record will insert. i am attaching to one dyanamo Db table but the lambda function call involked mutltiple times even if i add one record.

Can some one give an insight on this.

Thank you

Comment: Did you check the cloudwatch logs? Usually this happens when the Lambda Function crashes during the execution, so the stream event keeps "retrying".

Comment: Can you try to print the event and see the logs, to see what is going on?

Comment: Thanks @TomMelo for making a good point. I will check if that is the case.